# React bootstrap NavBar not compiling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

The code snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem} from 'react-bootstrap';

class Navigation extends Component {
  render(){
    return (

  <Navbar>
    <Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Brand>
        Github Searcher
      </Navbar.Brand>
    </Navbar.Header>

    <Nav>
      <NavItem href="#"> Login </NavItem>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar>

    )
  }
}
export default Navigation;
```

Getting this error message:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `Navigation`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could reproduce your error message and there are 2 issues what I have found for you.

**First issue:**

There is a small typo in the `import` part. You can correct if you change the first line from `Import React, { Component } from 'react'` to `import React, { Component } from 'react'`.

**Second issue:**

Which is related to the `Element type is invalid: expected a string` error message.

In `react-bootstrap` documentation I have found the following for [`NavbarHeader`](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/migrating/#navbarheader):

> removed, not present in v4

So `Navbar.Header` needs to be removed and it will work like charm.

I guess you can do something like this:

```
class Navigation extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar>
        <Navbar.Brand>
          Github Searcher
        </Navbar.Brand>

        <Nav>
          <NavItem href="#"> Login </NavItem>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar>
    )
  }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes sorry about that; in copy pasting the code this mistake was made in the actual code 'i' is in lower case. And yes after removing Navbar.Header the error is removed. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Import of first line should replace by import.
components are not included.